# export data from the PHP files to the form of Excel or Word

Tags: php

I want to export data from the PHP files to the form of Excel or Word note that outputs should be protected (unedit) just for reading
can you help me with code PLZ

Comment: Sorry, but we're not here to write your code for you. Why don't you lookup 'PHP COM interop' on Google? I'm sure there are many tutorials

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Html to DOC , XLS and ODF convertor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972924/php-html-to-doc-xls-and-odf-convertor)

Answer (score 3):

You haven't described what you have tried so far, so here's just two links to good libraries for generating those files via php:

- Excel: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/
- MSWord: http://phpword.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

here's a simple html table to excel file or to any file you want just replace the content-type: text/xls to a right content type.

search @google for content types

```
 <?php
 header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT\n");
 header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
 header("Content-type: text/xls;\n"); 
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"testfile.xls\";\n\n");
 ?>
 <table>
 <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>a</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>a</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>a</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

save to filename.php and see what happens.

Comment: That's *not* an Excel file, it's a hack.

Comment: yes it is. but it also works fine. its not gonna harm you.

Comment: It's harmful in the sense that this happens to work with Excel (does it even work with all version of it?), but not necessarily with other software that can read Excel files, but does not expect an HTML table in an "Excel file". Admittedly, the OP just vaguely specifies "Excel and Word", but XLS is a file format, not an application!

Comment: i try to use this link http://fundisom.com/phparadise/php/databases/mySQL_to_excel its do good (but) there is one more thing the output of this operation can be edit i want the output only for Reading

Answer (score 0):

This is for Excel for Word Change Content Type to application/ms-word and Filename with DOC or DOCX extention from XLS and

> Note : I'm not sure about content type i'm using windows so please
>   search content type on google for your version

```
<?php
$content = "This \t is \t testing \t\n";
 header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT\n");
 header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
 header("Content-type: text/ms-vnd.ms-excel;\n"); 
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"exceloutput.xls\";\n\n");
echo $content; 
?>
```